# FS.Collection instance returning undefined when using find()

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm somewhat new at web development so I apologize if I am using FSCollection incorrectly.

I have a FS.Collection instance that takes in audio files

```
LectureAudio = new FS.Collection("lectureAudio", {
    stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem("lectureAudio", {
        path:"~/digicog/audioUpload",
        filter: {
            allow: {
                contentTypes: ['audio/*'],
                extensions: ['mp3', 'wav', 'MP3', 'WAV']
            }
        }
    })]
});
```

And I am using an input file element to insert audio files into collection.

```
Template.audioControl.events({
  'change #lecAudioPath': function (event) {
    var files = document.getElementById("lecAudioPath").files;
    if(files.length != 0){  
      var lecName = Router.current().params._id;
      var audioFile = new FS.File(files[0]);
      audioFile.metadata = {LectureId: lecName};
      LectureAudio.insert(audioFile);
    }
   }
});
```

However when I type in `LectureAudio.find().fetch()` in the console for testing, I get empty brackets [ ].
Even though when I check my mongo database using:

```
>db.getCollection("cfs.lectureAudio.filerecord").find()
```

I see that my collection is populated.

```
{ "_id" : "wwyQtZZNwicbheCch", "copies" : { "lectureAudio" : { "name" : "fWnQyQpEWSXRDeuJq.mp3" } }, "original" : { "name" : "test1.mp3", "updatedAt" : ISODate("2013-08-16T16:07:40Z"), "size" : 8087475, "type" : "audio/mp3" }, "uploadedAt" : ISODate("2015-03-07T06:05:53.589Z") }
{ "_id" : "3rBbFfnGAT3Z8Bkti", "copies" : { "lectureAudio" : { "name" : "Efn235HcCyGrm5TPx.mp3" } }, "original" : { "name" : "test2.mp3", "updatedAt" : ISODate("2013-08-16T16:07:52Z"), "size" : 8806339, "type" : "audio/mp3" }, "uploadedAt" : ISODate("2015-03-07T06:17:06.234Z") }
{ "_id" : "RJ7LLH7XhgG2PnP9g", "copies" : { "lectureAudio" : { "name" : "fWnQyQpEWSXRDeuJq.mp3" } }, "original" : { "name" : "test3.mp3", "updatedAt" : ISODate("2013-08-16T16:07:52Z"), "size" : 8806339, "type" : "audio/mp3" }, "uploadedAt" : ISODate("2015-03-07T06:18:30.454Z") }
{ "_id" : "9YY33kFFbP7oBMjmr", "copies" : { "lectureAudio" : { "name" : "y7KQmq3ReqcP7Pzyw.mp3" } }, "original" : { "name" : "test4.mp3", "updatedAt" : ISODate("2013-08-16T16:07:40Z"), "size" : 8087475, "type" : "audio/mp3" }, "uploadedAt" : ISODate("2015-03-07T20:50:21.226Z") }
```

How do I get the collection to show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably forgot to publish and subscribe to the collection.

On the server:

```
Meteor.publish('lecture_audio', function () {
  return LectureAudio.find();
}
```

And on client:

```
Meteor.subscribe('lecture_audio');
```

More info in the docs [here](http://docs.meteor.com/%23/full/publishandsubscribe)

Comment: Yes! That worked thank you so much! I had a publish in my server folder and in my Router for the page that the template renders on a waitOn statement but for some reason those did not work.